# Accessing members within mainThread from Activity or Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a class called MainGamePanel that extends SurfaceView where I run a thread that handles my updating and drawing code. Then I have an activity which runs editor.xml file which contains a Relative layout which runs my MainGamePanel and a FrameLayout which I am using as a container to hold a fragment. So I have the MainGamePanel taking up 2/3 of the screen and the fragment is on the right taking the remaining 1/3 of the screen.

The fragment contains a button that I want to use to reset objects that are located within my MainGamePanel. How can I access a member of MainGamePanel from my fragment or vice versa?

Here is the code for my fragment where I check for the button click

```
Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.resetGrid_button);

// A simple OnClickListener for our button. You can see here how a Fragment can encapsulate
// logic and views to build out re-usable Activity components.
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Activity activity = getActivity();

        if (activity != null) 
            Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.reset_button, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    }

});
```

Instead of just doing the toast I would like to have it reset some objects located in my MainGamePanel surfaceView class. Thank you for your time and any information you can send my way.

Answered:
I figured out that I have to get a handle to my view inside of my activity and have the activity access the information. Then when the user clicks the button in my fragment, I let the activity know and update the information.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: That does explain how to communicate between the fragments and the activity but my MainGamePanel class is a custom surfaceView class and this is the class I need to communicate with so I am still confused on this.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create an interface to communicate between the Activity and Fragment,

follow this example -
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

once your Activity knows about the pressed button you should call a public method within your custom class that will handle the desired logic.